# In Java change List to Int

Tags: java

I want to change that `List number` to `int` so I can use it as part of an if statement

I tried almost every way I can

```
import java.util.*;
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    List number = new ArrayList();

    number.add(100);
    number.add(1000);
    number.add(10000);

    int[] changedNumber = number.stream();

    int A = chagedNumber.get[2];
    int B = chagedNumber.get[0];

    if (A > B) {

        System.out.println(number.get(2) + " is bigger than " + number.get(0));

    }   else {

        System.out.println(number.get(2) + " is smaller than" + number.get(0));

    }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you want to do? Get the first and last element of the list and compare them? What about ordering the list? Also, welcome to SO ;)

Answer (score 3):

Arrays nor streams have a `get` method.

Try only using the list index

```
List<Integer> number = new ArrayList<>();

number.add(100);
number.add(1000);
number.add(10000);

int a = number.get(2);
int b = number.get(0);

if (a > b) {

} else {

}
```

Note: You can also use `Arrays.asList(10, 1000, 10000)`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use:

```
List<Integer> number = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then, in your `if` statement:

```
if (number.get(2) > number.get(0)) { ...
```

Using `List<Integer>` will use [autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) to convert from Integer to int automatically.